# Unexpected language name displayed on the App Store

Tags: ios, app-store

We just submitted a new app on the app store localized in **english** and **french**.

The only .lproj folders in the app bundle are `fr.lproj` and `en.lproj`.

In the english App Store page we can read **En, French** instead of **English, French**. In french we can read **Français, En** instead of **Français, Anglais**.

Any idea why it is displayed **En** instead of **English**?